# can't display compund image below a text in pycharm (macOS)

Tags: python, tkinter

```
from tkinter import *

window = Tk()

photo = PhotoImage(file='nft.png')

label = Label(window,
              #text="kaizen nft",
              font=('Ariel',40,'italic'),
              fg='green',
              bg='black',
              relief=RAISED,
              bd=10,
              padx=12,
              pady=12,
              image=photo,
              compound='bottom')
label.pack()
#label.place(x=0,y=0)


window.mainloop()
```

tried learning labels in graphical user interface (macOS)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

- Add namespace `from tkmacosx import Label`
- Do not use wildcard. Use `import tkinter as tk`.
- Create function for `pressed_label()`.
- Use `.config` to update photo.

Edit:
Here is link: https://pypi.org/project/tkmacosx/

```
py -m pip install tkmacosx
```

Snippet:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkmacosx import Label


window = tk.Tk()

photo = tk.PhotoImage(file='p2.png')

def pressed_label():
    label.config(image=photo)

label = tk.Label(window,
              #text="kaizen nft",
              font=('Ariel',40,'italic'),
              fg='green',
              bg='black',
              #relief=tk.RAISED,
              bd=10,
              padx=12,
              pady=12,
              #image=photo,
              compound='bottom')
 
label.pack()

pressed_label()
window.mainloop()
```

Comment: You might want to add a link on how to install `tkmacosx` in case OP hasn't installed it yet. You aren't using it `tkmacosx.Label` importing it and you are missing a closing bracket on the last line. Also why did you put the `label.config` in a function instead of calling it immediately after creating `label`?

Comment: Thank you. I always forget something. No. you done need prefix.

Comment: Copied code and tried it after installing `tkmacosx` , still didn't work for the border style `relief` option set to **RAISED**. Might be they are just unusable for labels on mac cause I set it to **RIDGE** and **GROOVE** now and those worked. I'll use either of the two cause they work just fine. Thank you!

Comment: Actually this solution still uses `tk.Label` not `Label` from `tkmacosx` module.